# Can you rely on the cashier?

Tags: halacha, transactions, gezel-stealing

If a cashier or other low level employee makes a financial decision in your favor ("keep the change" or "I'll let you use that coupon even if it expired" etc.), without checking with a manager/owner, may one rely on that employee, or is it considered stealing? Does it matter if the store is owned by a Jew or a gentile? Please cite sources.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11975/759

Comment: Also sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12180/train-ticket-not-collected-destroy

Answer (score 5):

> "The hand of the employee is like the hand of the employer"  (Bava Metzia 10a.)

I would say that, unless you have a reason to believe that the cashier is trying to his cheat his employer by giving you a special deal, you can rely on the cashier's decision.

Here is an [interesting shiur](http://www.baishavaad.com/y_second_seder/cm_parsha/R%20Yosef%20Greenwald%20-%20Parshas%20Bo.mp3) that gives more detail on this concept, and practical applications thereof: